# SSRS blank parameter that displays all fields during initial load?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to modify a report to be more user friendly and expand the search capability into multiple fields. Right now, the parameter field requires a default value of '%' in order to list all output from SQL query. I want the parameter box to be **blank** for the user, while still listing all output from query upon **initial** loading. It seems I have tried everything, forcing me to attempt a different strategy.

I added a 2nd empty parameter: **Input** *(figuring the SearchString parm with default value of '%" eventually being hidden)*, and using logic to compare fields. Hoping to trick the report.

```html
=iif (IsNothing(Parameters!Input.Value),Parameters!SearchString.Value,"%"& Parameters!Input.Value & "%")
```

This almost works, but the report is blank upon initial running, and it requires to click run report to get desired results. I simply want the report to run like a wildcard is supplied, but leave the paramter for the user *blank*.

Any direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Couldn't you hide the first parameter containing the default value of '%' to get your initial run?

Comment: Exactly what I did, but doing that causes the report to "not run" upon opening. I have to click "run report" or hit enter. At that time, it works as I hoped...all data is displayed, and I have a blank box to enter a search term. I wan tto get away from having to do anything to get all data upon opening report.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is check for blanks in your query.

```
select
    Field1, 
    Field2
from 
    TheTable 
where 
    (@Parameter1 = '' or Field1 like @Parameter1)
    and (@Parameter2 = '' or Field2 like @Parameter2)
```

In the above, blank parameter values cause the parameter to be effectively ignored by the query rather than requiring a match-all wildcard. Also note that `like '%'` will exclude records with a null value in the field, whereas my approach will include them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your parameter allows blanks, but does not allow nulls.

Set the parameters default value to

```
=""
```

The report will then run when first viewing it (assuming any other parameters have been set)

Then you just need to modify the parameter of your query to pass `%` if the param is blank

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS try to set parameter as nullable with default = NULL and update your where part in sql code like:

```
select * from table
where (table.parameter = @parameter or @parameter is null)
```